# Monitor for programming: uw vs color gamut

Tags: monitors

Im currently using an hp 34f curved monitor and I was thinking to change this monitor since it feels too big and I find myself centering my apps in the middle of the screen.

I dont use the pc for gaming but I do appreciate impressive colors.

I was thinking to replace the hp monitor with other 16:9 monitor where the options are:

1. Msi g272qpf
2. Msi modern md271ul uhd

The first one will have the same ddp but have more impressive color gamut.

The second has better color gamut + 4k

I feel like getting the first one since it has vesa mount but my question is will there be much difference if both screens have the same ddp but different color gamuts? How big can be the dci-p3 effect if both screen have same resolution?

My budget is around 400$ even tho that I cant find too many models in my area for that budget with this spec except for those I mentioned.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## [Asus ProArt PA279CRV](https://www.asus.com/displays-desktops/monitors/proart/proart-display-pa279crv/) - $470

[image]

It's on the higher end of your budget, but I think this monitor should hit all of your requirements, while providing an excellent high-resolution, wide color-gamut viewing experience.

([Most of my info is pulled from this review by PC World.](https://www.pcworld.com/article/1794810/asus-proart-pa279crv-review.html))

**Pros:**

- 27" IPS @ 3840x2160
- VESA mountable, with a nice included stand
- Wide color gamut: 100% of sRGB, 99% of DCI-P3, and 98% of Adobe RGB
- Factory-calibrated with easy-to-switch color presets
- Very strong I/O, including USB-C with 96W of PD and an internal DisplayPort MST hub for daisy-chaining

**Mids:**

- Good but not class-leading color accuracy (ΔE of 1.41 out of the box; a ΔE of <2 is generally considered good enough for color-accurate content creation, but there are similarly priced monitors that do better)
- HDR 400 certified, but no local dimming
- 60 Hz refresh rate

**Cons:**

- Poor motion blur performance

Comment: Thank you,will check this one

Comment: So i checked this monitor. Do you this there is much visible difference between the colors of my current monitor to this? Basically its moving from "2k" to 4k with better color gamut which i dont habe idea how visible it is.

Comment: I think it’ll be noticeable, this monitor supports a very wide color gamut. It’s not going to have the “wow factor” of going to a monitor with better HDR support, but if you want that, you’ll probably want to step up to a monitor with full-array local dimming or an OLED—both of which will be more pricy.